# C# Console App Closes when I use DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#

**Thank you for helping, I solved it already**

I was making a file downloader app today and when I wanted to use the 'DownloadProgressChanged' event to create something like this:

```
[/] Download started.
[/] Download progress: 50%
[/] Download progress: 100%
[+] Download completed.
```

I used the 'DownloadProgressChanged' and 'DownloadFileCompleted' events:

```
WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(adress), path);
```

and then I made a reference to those events:

```
wClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
wClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WClient_DownloadFileCompleted;

private static void WClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
// throw new NotImplementedException();
Console.Write("[");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Write("+");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
Console.Write("] : ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
Console.WriteLine("Press a key to close the installer");

Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void WClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
// throw new NotImplementedException();
Console.Write("[");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.Write("/");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
Console.Write("] : ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Download progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
}
```

When I executed the console app, and started downloading, the files got downloaded to my desktop but the console didn't wait for the user to press a key and didn't show any of the download logs.

Full main() code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
    string link = "cant share the link";
    string dPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\file.txt";

    Console.Clear();
    Console.Write("[");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("+");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.Write("] : ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to download the file");

    Console.ReadKey();
    
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

    wClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), dPath);


    wClient.DownloadProgressChanged += WClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
    wClient.DownloadFileCompleted += WClient_DownloadFileCompleted;

}

private static void WClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // throw new NotImplementedException();
    Console.Write("[");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.Write("+");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.Write("] : ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to close the installer");

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void WClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // throw new NotImplementedException();
    Console.Write("[");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.Write("/");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.Write("] : ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.WriteLine("Download progress: " + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
}
```

Comment: It'd help if you also showed your whole `Main`.

Comment: So you are waiting for a key press in the DownloadFileCompleted handler, but what about the time before it is called?

Comment: @KlausGütter Hey, I added `Console.ReadKey();` in it because when the download finishes, you press a key then the app closes. If I don't put that the app would close instantly when the download finishes, just like cmd's `pause >nul`

Comment: Your `Main` method is simply acting as expected.  It's returning (void in this case).  Also you should subscribe to events prior to the download.

Comment: But your Main method terminates just after you started the download - you have to put the `Console.ReadKey` there

Comment: @KlausGütter tysm! it worked fine.